# Creating Touchjoints/Mousejoints on small objects in box2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm using Cocos2d iPhone with Box2D to create a basic physics engine.

Occasionally the user is required to drag around a small box2D object.

Creation of touchjoints on small objects is a bit hit and miss, with the game engine seeing it as a tap on blank space as often as actually creating the appropriate touchjoint. In practice this means the user is constantly mashing their fingers against the screen in vain attempts to move a stubborn object. I want the game to select small objects easily without this 'hit and miss' effect.

[image: This (awesome) picture shows what I'm talking about in cartoon format. It's also a loose allergy to the meaning of life.]

I could create the small objects with larger sensors around them, but this is not ideal because objects above a certain size (around 40px diameter) don't need this extra layer of complexity; and the small objects are simply the big objects scaled down to size.

What are some strategies I could use to allow the user experience to be better when moving small objects?

Here's the AABB code in ccTouchBegan:

```
b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(touchLocation.x/PTM_RATIO, touchLocation.y/PTM_RATIO);

    b2AABB aabb;
    b2Vec2 delta = b2Vec2(1.0/PTM_RATIO, 1.0/PTM_RATIO); 
    //Changing the 1.0 here to a larger value doesn't make any noticeable difference.
    aabb.lowerBound = locationWorld - delta;
    aabb.upperBound = locationWorld + delta;
    SimpleQueryCallback callback(locationWorld);
    world->QueryAABB(&callback, aabb);

    if(callback.fixtureFound){
      //dragging code, updating sprite location etc.
    }
```

SimpleQueryCallback code:

```
    class SimpleQueryCallback : public b2QueryCallback
    {
    public:
    b2Vec2 pointToTest;
    b2Fixture * fixtureFound;

    SimpleQueryCallback(const b2Vec2& point) {
        pointToTest = point;
        fixtureFound = NULL;
    }

    bool ReportFixture(b2Fixture* fixture) {
        b2Body* body = fixture->GetBody();
        if (body->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody) {
            if (fixture->TestPoint(pointToTest)) {
                fixtureFound = fixture;
                return false;
            }
        }        
        return true;
    }        
};
```

Comment: I would make delta larger, and get the callback class to store all the fixtures it found instead of just one. Then go through the list and evaluate which fixture is really the best candidate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I make the delta bigger (say 50.0 or 100.0) I still have the same problem, even if there is only one object in that aabb rect. It's not that it's choosing another object, it's that it is choosing empty space.

Comment: Depends how you do the "evaluate the best candidate" part... you could accept objects that are within a certain range of the touch, even if the touch is not on top of them (otherwise there was no point making delta bigger :)

Comment: Ok, so that would be in the SimpleQueryCallback class, in the ReportFixture method? I understand that ReportFixture returns true or false based on pointToTest which is passed in from the touchlocation. How can I test points other than touch location which are within the aabb rect? (This is probably the answer I'm after with this question).

Comment: You would replace the 'b2Fixture* fixtureFound' member with a vector or something that could store multiple fixtures instead of just one. In ReportFixture you would put every fixture into this list, and return true every time so that you get all the fixtures in the AABB. Then after QueryAABB finishes you'll have a list of fixtures to go through and do that "evaluate the best candidate" part.

Comment: Thankyou. I think this is probably the correct answer. Does report fixture iterate for each fixture inside the aabb rect?

Comment: Yeah, it reports each fixture as it is found, until you return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing - thanks to iforce2d, was change ReportFixture in SimpileQueryCallback to:

```
bool ReportFixture(b2Fixture* fixture) {
    b2Body* body = fixture->GetBody();
    if (body->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody) {

        //if (fixture->TestPoint(pointToTest)) {
        fixtureFound = fixture;

        return true;
        //}
    }        
    return true;
}
```

And increase the delta to 10.0/PTM_RATIO.

Answer (score 0):

What about a minimum collision box for touches? Objects with less than 40px diameter use the 40px diameter, all larger objects use their actual diameter.

Comment: Hi LC2D. I was thinking about something like that, but I'm not sure how or where I would implement it; can you point me in the direction of an example or some documentation? My touchjoint creation is very bare-bones at the moment.